# Make Search Box do not collapse at xs breakpoint in bootstrap

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a search box with input element and submit button. I am working in bootstrap. At xs breakpoint submit button goes into another line. I want to make the whole forum never collapse but changes its size as it happens by default

```
<form class="form-inline quick-search-form" role="form" action="search.php">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Keyword(s)">
    <button type="submit" id="quick-search" class="btn btn-custom"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search custom-glyph-color"></span></button>
</div>
<div class="pad-top-20">Examples Background, Banner, Brochure</div>
```

Comment: Please look at the Bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, bootstrap inline form will always collapse on xs (from the documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)

> Add .form-inline to your form (which doesn't have to be a ) for
>   left-aligned and inline-block controls. **This only applies to forms
>   within viewports that are at least 768px wide.**

You need to override them so it will never collapse

```
.form-group input{
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Working plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/KFvIrUSwioIwWG6hZAA1?p=preview